# Entity Framework Code First Junction Table duplicating data on Insert (Fluent API)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, code-first

I'm currently creating a Windows 8.1 app connected to an Azure Mobile Service and using EF6 Code First to create the database.

The tables currently are `Account`, `User`, `Business`, `ProfilePicture` and `Blob`. When a profile is created, an entry will be inserted into the `Account` table, and then depending on the user's selection, an entry into the `User` or `Business` table.

When an `Account` is instantiated, a new `User` or `Business`, and `ProfilePicture` models are created within the `Account` model.

The way I intend on implementing the `ProfilePicture` is to have a default profile picture set when an `Account` is created, therefore I select the default profile picture blob from the table and use it when creating the `ProfilePicture` model within the `Account`. The issue I'm having is that when passing in the `Blob` returned from the query, it seems to also insert the blob into the `Blob` table, thus duplicating the entry, and I've no idea why. (Hopefully this will be a bit clearer with the App.xaml.cs code below)

I'm not sure at all why this is happening. Still getting to grips with FluentAPI so my knowledge isn't the best, so any tips/guidance, as well as help, would be much appreciated! Thanks.

---

(sorry there's so much code)

#### Service Side

**DataObjects**

```
public class Account : EntityData
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public Business Business { get; set; }
    public ProfilePicture ProfilePicture { get; set; }
}

public class Business : EntityData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ContactNo { get; set; }

    public Account Account { get; set; }
}

public class User : EntityData
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Account Account { get; set; }
}

public class ProfilePicture : EntityData
{
    public Account Account { get; set; }
    public Blob Blob { get; set; }
}

public class Blob : EntityData
{
    public string ContainerName { get; set; }
    public string ResourceName { get; set; }
    public string SASQueryString { get; set; }
    public string ImageURI { get; set; }
}
```

**Entity Configurations** (Only their constructors):

```
public AccountConfig()
{
    HasKey(account => account.Id);
    Property(account => account.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    Property(account => account.Password).IsRequired();
    Property(account => account.Username).IsRequired();
}

public BusinessConfig()
{
    Property(business => business.ContactNo).IsRequired();
    Property(business => business.Name).IsRequired();

    HasRequired(business => business.Account)
        .WithOptional(account => account.Business)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete();
}

public UserConfig()
{
    Property(user => user.FirstName).IsRequired();
    Property(user => user.LastName).IsRequired();

    HasRequired(user => user.Account)
        .WithOptional(account => account.User)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete();
}

public ProfilePictureConfig()
{
    HasRequired(profile => profile.Account).
        WithRequiredDependent(account => account.ProfilePicture).
        WillCascadeOnDelete();
    HasRequired(profile => profile.Blob);
}

public BlobConfig()
{
    HasKey(blob => blob.Id);
    Property(blob => blob.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    Property(blob => blob.ContainerName).IsRequired();
    Property(blob => blob.ImageURI).IsRequired();
    Property(blob => blob.ResourceName).IsRequired();
    Property(blob => blob.SASQueryString).IsRequired();
}
```

#### Client Side

**Models**

```
public class Account
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public Business Business { get; set; }
    public ProfilePicture ProfilePicture { get; set; }
}

public class Business
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ContactNo { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class ProfilePicture
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public Account Account { get; set; }
    public Blob Blob { get; set; }
}

public class Blob
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ContainerName { get; set; }
    public string ResourceName { get; set; }
    public string SASQueryString { get; set; }
    public string ImageURI { get; set; }
}
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
Blob blob1 = new Blob
        {
            ContainerName = "Container1",
            ImageURI = "Uri1",
            ResourceName = "DefaultProfilePic",
            SASQueryString = "SomethingGoesHere"
        };
        await BlobTable.InsertAsync(blob1);

        List<Blob> pictures = await BlobTable.Where(blob => blob.ContainerName == "Container1").ToListAsync();

        Account account = new Account
        {
            Username = "User123",
            User = new User
            {
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Smithy"
            },
            ProfilePicture = new ProfilePicture
            {
                Blob = pictures.First()
            },
            Password = "Password123"
        };

        string result = await MobileService.InvokeApiAsync<Account, string>("customAccount", account);
```